# MultiThreading using a ready stack

Tags: c#, multithreading, stack, locking, monitor

I have an issue that is causing performance problems.  I have a map application and some tiles are generated on the fly others are cached and retried.  Both methods using mutlithreading.  The problem is that there are performance problems if tiles are generated on the fly and there is a lot of data to retrieve.  The user pans/zooms and the application must query everything in an envelope and return the image every time the map changes.  If I lock the method that generates a tile on the fly then the cached files generate quickly but it takes forever for the dynamic tiles to generate especially if the user pans and zooms a lot.  My question is this:

Is there a way to implement a lock and then after the method is complete, access the last thread in the ready-queue?  I guess what I'm looking for is a ready-stack rather than a ready-queue.  This way the area where the user currently is will have it's tiles generated sooner than later.

I am using a local webservice to generate the tiles.  Here is what I have so far.

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: Sorry I didn't include code at first.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use any locking at all, just use a thread safe stack implementation, like [`System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentStack`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267331(v=vs.110).aspx) to hold the queue of work to do. You then just have your pool of worker threads all push and or pull the work to do from this stack individually.

You can very easily implement the entire work queue system with .NET 4.5 using `Parallel.ForEach` and a Blocking Collection. You provided no code so I kind of had to make something up for a example, but it could work something like this.

```
public void StartTileProcessor()
{
    //The default for a BlockingCollection is a Queue, but you can pass in a stack for the underlying collection and it will behave as a stack.
    var stack = new BlockingCollection<UnprocessedTileMetadata>(new ConcurrentStack<UnprocessedTileMetadata>());

    var processorThread = Task.Run(() => ProcessTiles(stack));

    _yourGui.TileRequested += (sender, e) => stack.Add(e.RequestedTile);

    //...
}

/// <summary>
/// The method for processing tiles, takes from the stack and returns to the output.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="inputStack">The blocking collection that represents the input stack.</param>
private void ProcessTiles(BlockingCollection<UnprocessedTileMetadata> inputStack)
{
    //This is done so the foreach does not try to buffer requests from the consuming enumerable, the next item it processes will be the last added to the stack.
    var partitioner = Partitioner.Create(inputStack.GetConsumingEnumerable(), EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering);
    Parallel.ForEach(partitioner, (unprocessedTile) =>
    {
        ProcessedTile tile = GenerateOrGetFromCache(unprocessedTile);
        _yourGui.SendToDisplay(tile);
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear.  I am using a local webservice to generate the tiles.  Here is what I have so far.

Comment: Don't put code in comments. Update your question showing what you have done.